# How to troubleshooting wireless network issue with ip-network falling periodically?

Tags: wireless-networking, troubleshooting

All wireless clients some times a day can't see anybody in the network: no AP (ping or web-interface), no Internet-access, no each other, but Wi-Fi signal is ok for them. In the same time wire-connected Raspberry Pi can ping router and have access to Internet.

Wireless AP is TP-Link TL-WR1043ND with 3.13.13 Build 130428 Rel.58290n firmware (latest firmware and other router same model was tried already with no effect). It connected to ISP through VoIP gateway with PPPoE, works in n-only mode, WPA-2 security, makes port forwarding and DynDNS.

Wireless clients are:

- Samsung notebook with Linux Mint 17
- Samsung smartphone with stock Android 4.1.2
- Wexler tablet with stock Android 4.2.2

Wired client is Raspberry Pi model B with Raspbian.

What can I do for troubleshooting this issue in my environment?

Comment: Does it happen around the same time block each day?. Look for common patterns. Have you rebooted the wireless clients during the time of no network access? There should be some kind of network capture application you can run on one (or more) of the clients to see what is happening to packets during the time of temporary outage.

Comment: I can't catch a patterns, seems random. No, I not reboot clients, and I can't see, how it can helps me to troubleshoot an issue. I can use any tools, if you can tell me their names and explain, what kind of magic I should find in packets.

Comment: Before disconnect wireshark on notebook catch a lot of errors `Ethernet Unknown: Invalid length/type: 0x05e0 (1504)`. A guy [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1668277.html) solved something like this with wi-fi channel changing. But wavemon doesn't show me another network on my channel. I disabled auto channel selection on AP just in case.

Comment: Hard configured wi-fi channel doesn't help. I can't find any more information about this error.